# Drag/Drop from WPF to Excel

Tags: wpf, excel, drag-and-drop

Does anyone know if it possible to drag and drop an object from WPF to Excel?

It can be either an external WPF application or a WPF project hosted inside an elementhost of an Excel Addin.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at this previous entry and use that to derive what you are looking for:
[WPF: Drag and drop virtual files into Windows explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861214/wpf-drag-and-drop-virtual-files-into-windows-explorer)